# Как удалить определенный элемент из списка

Tags: python

Предположим, у меня есть список из имён, и мне необходимо удалить только один элемент без использования индексов.

Comment: Метод `список.remove('элемент')` не устроит?

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
# удалим элемент со значением b  
lst.remove('b')
```